# Script to calculate Uncle Bob's "Agile PPP" code metrics for C#

Tags: c#, code-metrics

I am reading [Agile PPP for C#](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/84983.Agile_Principles_Patterns_and_Practices_in_C_), and at some point Uncle Bob presents interesting metrics for design quality:

These are:

- **H** (relational cohesion) = (R + 1) / N, where:

  - R = number of internal relations inside a component;
  - N = number of classes inside that component.
- **I** (Instability) = Ce / (Ca + Ce), where:

  - Ca = afferent couplings;
  - Ce = efferent couplings;
- **A** (Abstractedness) = Na / Nc, where:

  - Nc = number of classes;
  - Na = number of *abstract* classes;
- **D'** (normalized Distance from main sequence) = abs(A + I - 1) / sqrt(2), where:

  - "main sequence" is, inside an A vs I cartesian plot, the diagonal line formed by the positions where A + I = 1;

The most intriguing part is this (directly from the book):

> The metrics we describe have been successfully applied to a number of projects since 1994.
>
> *Several automatic tools* will calculate them for you, and *they are not difficult to calculate by hand*.
>
> It is also not difficult to write a simple *shell, Python, or Ruby script* to walk through your source files and calculate them.
>
> For an example of a shell script, you can download `depend.sh` from the freeware section of objectmentor.

I couldn't find this `depend.sh` script, and I'm not sure if I agree that these metrics are easy to calculate by hand, or via some script (I would like to use Python for that, if that was the case).

So, the questions are:

- Is there a free tool or script to calculate Uncle Bob's metrics for C# code? Visual Studio has some metrics, but they are different, and I don't really know or care how to interpret them;
- <strike>How should I approach the task to build my own script</strike> There is the famous "regex can't parse html" fact, and I wonder if C# code structure lends itself to the sort of "simple script" Uncle Bob is proposing, so that these metrics can be calculated. Should I even try?

Comment: Valid questions but the first one is an off-site resource request, which are off-topic. Given that you have decent specs you might want to look if [SoftwareRecs](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) could be of help. Your last bullet is too broad (or opinion based).

Comment: @rene could you help me to improve my questions so that they remain on topic?

Comment: @rene I edited my second bullet.

Comment: The resource request is covered I think. The broadness could be addressed if you start with a script your self for example to determine what classes are. Then ask a question about that. Then you proceed by asking a new question for each part of the metrics where try some bits and then hand off to the community.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, the automation model used to have classes and collections about classes. That could be a start. Or check the Reflection Namespace and ask about if that can help

Comment: A lot related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031135/what-is-abstractness-vs-instability-graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool NDepend computes [these metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#RelationalCohesion) and it makes easy to write your custom metrics through [C# Linq Queries](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL).

It is integrated in Visual Studio and also generates [report](http://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/) with Uncle Bob's metrics diagram.

A 14-day trial full featured edition is available for [download](http://www.ndepend.com/download).

[image: NDepend Uncle Bob's metrics diagram]